# created contacts groups are not visible

Tags: android, android-contacts

I created a contact group programmaticallyusing ContentProvider following is the piece of code
I traied

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, "saa")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, 1)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.DELETED, true)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, "saa")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "saa").build());

  getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

the problem is it is creating the group, but it is not visible in the groups list of People.
And how to delete the created group

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide me some solution

Comment: Is the account for account_name = saa and account_type = saa visible ?

Answer (score 0):

here a code snipped how I do it:

public static final String groupName = "some_name";

packageName = myContext.getPackageName();

```
/**
 * insert a new group 
 */
public void insertGroup() {

    if (debug)
        Log.i(TAG, "insertGroup() ");

    ContentResolver contentResolver = globalContext.getContentResolver();
    Uri insertResult;

    ContentValues groupValues;
    groupValues = new ContentValues();
    groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, groupName);
    groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.GROUP_VISIBLE, 1);
    groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.NOTES, groupName);
    groupValues
            .put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_NAME, Konst.accountName);
    groupValues.put(ContactsContract.Groups.ACCOUNT_TYPE, packageName);
    insertResult = contentResolver.insert(
            ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, groupValues);
    if (debug)
        Log.d(TAG, "insertGroup() insertResult: " + insertResult.toString());

}
```